# How can Square Cash rely on the authenticity of the email sender to transfer funds?

Tags: email, square

I recently read about Square Cash, but this question keeps haunting me.

As far as I know, you can send an email with any "From" field you want regardless of the server/MX the actual email domain uses. Gmail has this capability, where you can simply verifiy that you are the owner of an email via a simple email check, and start sending emails from that address.

If gmail can do that, I imagine if I setup an email server, I can do that too.

How can Square rely on the authenticity of the email sender to transfer funds?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific web-based service with no API.

Comment: It's about the email system using Square as an specific use case.